# passing object of class to another class

Tags: java, class, reference

I have two classes. `Class A` and `Class B`.

I have a function in `Class A` that i would like to use in `class B`. I was thinking about passing a reference of `Class A` to the constructor of `Class B` and then call the function after that.

Would that work? Can someone show me an example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well you can't pass by reference in java. A good read here http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html .

Comment: @CoolBeans.  You can't pass by reference, but you can pass a reference.  And that's in fact what happens naturally when you think you're passing an object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it will work. And it's a decent way to do it. You just pass an *instance* of class A:

```
public class Foo {
   public void doFoo() {..} // that's the method you want to use
}

public class Bar {
   private Foo foo;
   public Bar(Foo foo) {
      this.foo = foo;
   }

   public void doSomething() {
      foo.doFoo(); // here you are using it.
   }
}
```

And then you can have:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar(foo);
bar.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this

```
class ClassA {
    public ClassA() {    // Constructor
    ClassB b = new ClassB(this); 
}

class ClassB {
    public ClassB(ClassA a) {...}
}
```

The this keyword essentially refers to the object(class) it's in.